# Open data form at a chosen position

Tags: c#, datagridview

**Scenario:**

I have a simple GUI for a membership database with a `datagridview` with each `row` being a member, and a `membership details form`. I have created an `event handler` for the the click event of a `datagridview` row header to open the `membership details form`.

**Question:**

I would like to know how to get the `details form` to open and automatically show the details for the member on which I clicked the row header.

**I.e.** If I click on the row header for member number three make the data form open with member number three. See image here: [image]

I figured I should pass the value of the ID column to the constructor of the `member details form`. But what should the constructor do with that `int`?

This is what I tried and it didn't work:

```
public MemberDetails(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext[ membershipDataSet, "Members"].Position = id;
}
```

Comment: Upload your visual example somewhere and give us a link

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the values of the row to the constructor of the `details form` as you already mentioned.

Now you need to assign those values to your form `controls` like `textboxes`,`datetimepicker` etc.

Code for `Details Form constructor`:

```
public DetailsForm(int ID, string LastName, string FirstName, string DateOfBirth)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = ID.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = LastName;
    textBox3.Text = FirstName;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(DateOfBirth);
}
```

Code for `RowHeaderMouseClick` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //retrieving values from "datagridview1"
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    string LastName = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string FirstName = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string DateOfBirth = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    //instantiating "DetailsForm"
    DetailsForm DetailsFormObject = new DetailsForm(id, LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth);

    //displaying the form
    DetailsFormObject.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to the record identified by the argument `id` I used the MoveNextItem.PerformClick() method inside a for loop.

```
    public MemberDetails(int id)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.membersTableAdapter.Fill(this.membershipDataSet.Members);
                // navigate to item 
                for (int i = 0; i < id; i++)
                {
                    this.membersBindingNavigator.MoveNextItem.PerformClick();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Also, I've since realised that what I really need to do is implement a 3 layer design pattern (Presentation Layer, Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer). The functionality I was originally trying to achieve will be programmed in to the Business Logic Layer.